# Entity Framework selection with foreign key is empty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two tables in my model `Tree` and `TreeImage` the relation between these tables is one-many respectively, I have data in both tables, This is a database first model.

The problem that I have is when I select from table `Tree`, I can see the `TreeImage` property but it is empty, I expected this to have some values, as the relation between tables does exist, I don't think I should `Join` the `TreeImage` table or what is the benefit of having the `Relational Constrains` from the beginning.

**What should I do to see some value from `TreeUmage`**

Entities :

[image]

[image]

**Tree Class**

```
public partial class Tree
{
    public Tree()
    {
        this.TreeLeaves = new HashSet<TreeLeave>();
        this.UserTrees = new HashSet<UserTree>();
        this.TreeImages = new HashSet<TreeImage>();
    }

    public int TreeID { get; set; }
    public string TreeTitle { get; set; }
    public string TreeDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TreeLeave> TreeLeaves { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserTree> UserTrees { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TreeImage> TreeImages { get; set; }
}
```

**My Select query**

```
 using (var db = new ...())
        {
            return (from tree in db.Trees
                    select tree).ToList();
        }
```

**This code generates this output**

```
   [{"TreeID":1,"TreeTitle":"Red Mable","TreeDescription":"Hello 
 ","TreeLeaves":[],"UserTrees":[],"TreeImages":[]},...
```

I'm working on a project that required me to work with technology, and I couldn't get myself on the right path to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Include extension method.

```
using (var db = new ...())
{
    return (from tree in db.Trees.Include("TreeImages")
            select tree).ToList();
}
```

If you want to use a lambda expression you must add:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

And then you can use it like:

```
db.Trees.Include(t => t.TreeImages)
```

Comment: This works: return db.Trees.Include("TreeImages").ToList();

Comment: I completely forgot that method was taking a string parameter. Sorry about that. I'm glad you figured it out.